# Proving Transitivity

Tags: abstract-algebra, relations

> Consider a relation defined by $Z$ where $(a,b) = 2a^2 + b^2 -3ab = 0$
>
> Is the relation $R_1$ reflexive? symmetric? transitive? Is it an
>   equivalence relation?

I have said that it is reflexive as $$2(a)^2 + a^2 - 3(a)(a) = 0$$ $$3a^2 - 3a^2 = 0$$ $$0= 0$$

I said it wasn't symmetric and I proved it via an example where the element is (2,1)

$$ 2(2)^2 +(1)^2 -3(2)(1) ≠ 2(1)^2 + (2)^2 - 3(1)(2)$$
$$8+1-6 ≠ 2+ 4 -6$$
$$3≠0$$

I don't really know how to prove transitivity. I understand it that if (a,b) ∈ $R_1$ and (b,c) ∈ $R_1$ then (a,c) ∈ $R_1$.

Also, I understand that this relation cannot be an equivalence relation as it is not reflexive $and$ symmetric $and$ transitive.

Comment: The relation is reflexive. You proved it.

Comment: Well, to prove transitivity you must prove that $x\sim y$ and $y\sim z$ together imply $x\sim z$.

Comment: @Susobhan He knows it is reflexive, you parsed the last sentence wrongly (or at least not in the way the OP intended).

Comment: @Roy The relation isn't transitive. I immediately found a counterexample by considering $(1,2)$. Here I looked for a pair $(2,x)$ such that $(2,x)\in R_1$ and I hoped that $x$ was an integer (there are two possibilities) and $(1,x)\not \in R$ (reduces to one choice). It worked. **Edit:** What do you mean with "defined by $Z$"? I interpreted it as "defined in $\mathbb Z$".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relation of interest is not transitive, because $R_1(1,2)$ and $R_1(2,4)$ are true, but $R_1(1,4)$ is false.

By the way, a good specification of $R_1$ would be explicit about the values that the arguments can take. For example, you could use set-builder notation:

$$R_1 = \{(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \mid 2a^2+b^2−3ab=0\}$$

Also, if you're wondering how to tackle these problems in future, try using a computer program to find integer-valued counterexamples. My method was basically to put the formula into a spreadsheet, and toy with the numbers for 30 seconds. And viola, out popped a counterexample.